# linux intellij keeps crashing on linux

Tags: intellij-idea

My Intellij Idea IDE keeps crashing. No error messages. The window just disappear and then when I restart it starts re-indexing again and etc.

Here is a screenshot of all the error logs[image]

I have heard that this problem is caused by memory settings. Anyone knows where I can modify these settings on linux

Comment: "Here is a screenshot of all the error logs" - Have you considered opening the logs to see what the error is?

Comment: I tried but I couldnt really understand them

Comment: Post the full content of these crash reports somewhere.